# univalent odd function on unit disk, $f(z)^2=g(z^2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f a univalent (holom., 1-1) function on the unit disk and suppose $f(-z)=-f(z)$. Then prove that there exists a unique 1-1 holomorphic $g$ such that $g(z^2)=f(z)^2$.

I would like to confirm whether my solution is correct as it makes no use of complex analysis which makes me doubt I got it right.

Since f is odd, so $f=z+a_3z_3+a_5z^5+.....=zt(z)$, where $t(z)=1+b_2z^2+b_4z^4+b_6z^6+....$. Therefore $f^2(z)=z^2t^2(z)$, where $t^2$ is also even, i.e it is of the form $t^2(z)=1+c_2z^2+c_4z^4+....$

So set $h(z)=1+c_2z+c_4z^2+c_6z^3+...$ and then we have that $h(z^2)=t^2(z)$. Now for $g(z)=zh(z)$ we have the result. By the construction, it is clear that $g$ is unique.

So up until now we have shown that for any odd holomorphic function $f$, there exists a unique $g$ such that $g(z^2)=f(z)^2$, which seems bizarre as I haven't used the fact it is 1-1 at all, or the fact that we 're on a disk.

As for the fact that $g$ is 1-1, since $f$ is 1-1, we have that $f^2$ is at most 2-1. Suppose $g(z)=g(w)$ where clearly $z,w \neq 0$. Let $z_1,z_2$ such that $z_1^2=z_2^2=z$ and similarly $w_1, w_2$ the square roots of $w$. Then $f^2(z_1)=f^2(z_2)=f^2(w_1)=f^2(w_2)$, so $f^2$ is 4-1 which is a contradiction.

I am pretty sure I have somehow messed up the exercise as I have made no use of complex analysis, so I would appreciate any hints on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: First, you needed to use $f$ is holomorphic on the unit disc to show that $f$ is analytic at $0$ with a series converging on the unit disc, and also to show $g$ is defined on the unit disc.  Second, your method shows existence, not uniqueness, of $g$.

Comment: As Brian mentions, you need something more to get uniqueness. Also, you neglect the domain (of f) in your proof of 1-to-1. Thinking about where $z$, $w$, $z_i$, and $w_i$ all live should help allay your concerns about why the unit disk is relevant.